# How to create data entry with association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now I have models of users and their articles. However, how do I implement the articles controller so that it keeps track of which user is the author? Should I pass a parameter back or is there any API to use?

Answer (score 0):

In article model ,

```
belongs_to :user
```

and in user model,

```
has_many :articles
```

Now , you have one to many relation , from user to article . Just add an attribute author in user table. This is how u can apply the logic

Comment: What to do with the controller?

Comment: In controller you just have to add your basic action like (new,edit,create,update,) and so on. Most of your logic resides in model. Controller is just the thin skin between model and view.

Answer (score 0):

```
in app/models/article.rb

belongs_to :user

in app/models/user.rb

has_many :articles
```

> and in controller(new action) you will write
>
> current_user.articles.new
>
> or
>
> current_user.articles.build
>
> and in controller(create action) you will write
>
> current_user.articles.create(params[:article])
>
> or
>
> article = current_user.articles.build
>
> article.attributes = params[:article]
>
> and if you want to fetch only user's articles then you will do in edit
>   action
>
> current_user.articles.find(params[:id]), where params[:id] is article
>   id which is to be edited.
>
> and in controller(update action) you will write
>
> article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
>
> article.update_attributes(params[:article])